# Random numbers over periods (Using logical)

Tags: matlab, random, matrix

With the code below:

```
t=10;
period=9;
A=zeros(36,36,t);
for j=1:t
   A(7:period:end,7:period:end,j)=rand(1,1);
   A(8:period:end,8:period:end,j)=rand(1,1);
   A(9:period:end,9:period:end,j)=rand(1,1);
end
```

---

Edit: This is A. I've split them up into 9x9 visually so it's easier to see the pattern.

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

I'd like to make every single number which is labelled 1, a random number between 0 to 1. Is it necessary to create a vector(48,1) and then plug in the values where the 1s are?

---

Of course the numbers are not entirely random, the same three random numbers are being reproduced every ''period''.

Is there a simple way that can create random numbers so every single randomnly generated value is random?

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you describe your desired output more fully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was slightly trickier than I thought at first.  Here's my solution though:

```
A = zeros(36,36,t);
idx = sub2ind([36 36 t],repmat(34:36,1,t),repmat(34:36,1,t),repmat(1:t,1,3));
A(idx) = rand(length(idx),1);
```

The solution with logical indexing is:

```
A(logical(A)) = rand(nnz(A),1);
```

But you have to prepare `A` as the binary matrix given in the question.

Comment: Brilliant, bit of editting and it works to what I want beautifully. Thanks! Logical appears to be a very useful command.

Comment: Yes, logical indexing is awesome. My original solution wasn't right, so I wrote the above, then added back the original when I saw you figured it out.  Glad you got it.